# WARNING in Circular dependency detected: src\app\app.module.ts -> src\app\app.module.ngfactory.js -> src\app\app.module.ts

Tags: angular, service-workers

Tengo una aplicación con angular, y cuando intento

```
 ng build --prod
```

Siempre sale

```
WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
src\app\app.module.ts -> src\app\app.module.ngfactory.js -> 
src\app\app.module.ts
```

¿Por que sucede esto, y como puedo solucionarlo?

Muchas gracias por vuestra atención

Comment: enseña el contenido de tu src\app\app.module.ts

Comment: Además de lo que menciona Manuel, sería útil ver la estructura del proyecto, cuales son los otros módulos y, si en alguno no está importando un módulo que lo importe.

Comment: Eso pasa por que en el modulo `app.module.ts` tienes dentro de los imports `app.module.ngfactory.js` y dentro de `app.module.ngfactory.js` tienes un import a `app.module.ngfactory.js`. Esa es una dependencia circular.

Comment: Esto me ha pasado varias veces cuando tengo lo siguiente. Componente A que usa cierta funcionalidad de componente B, entonces en componente A pongo como provider o un objeto de componente B y viceversa, entonces a esto se el llama que tienes una dependencia circula, entonces debes deslindar la funcionalidad común en un componente o servicio aparte al que los dos puedan apuntar.